# Merging/concatenating two datasets on a specific column (different lengths)

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different datasets

```
df1
    Name Surname Age  Address
    Julian Ross   34  Main Street
    Mary   Jane   52  Cook Road

len(1200)

df2
    Name     Country   Telephone

    Julian   US         NA

len(800)
```

df1 contains the full list of unique names; df2 contains less rows as many Name were not added.
I would like to get a final dataset with the full list of names in df1 (and all the fields that are there) plus the fields in df2. I would then expect a final dataset of length 1200 with some empty fields corresponding to the missing name in df2.
I have tried as follows:

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('Name'),df2.set_index('Name')], axis=1, join='inner')
```

but it returns the length of the smallest dataset (i.e. 800).
I have also tried

```
df1.merge(df2, how = 'inner', on = ['Name'])
```

... same result.

I am not totally familiar with joining/merging/concatenating functions, even after reading the document https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html .
I know that probably this question will be a duplicate of some others and I will be happy to delete it if necessary, but I would be really grateful if you could provide same help and explaining how to get the expected result:

```
df

Name Surname Age Address Country Telephone
Julian Ross  34   Main Street US   NA
Mary Jane    52   Cook Road
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Use `pd.merge` like below:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='Name')

     Name Surname  Age      Address Country  Telephone
0  Julian    Ross   34  Main Street      US        NaN
1    Mary    Jane   52    Cook Road     NaN        NaN
```

If you want to keep the number of rows of `df1`, you have to use `how='left'` in the case where there is no duplicate names in `df2`.

Read [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Yes, thanks Corralien

Comment: Glad to read that. Hope it's more clear for you, now. Thanks for your support.